# Is it necessary to use the form to transfer data to the server?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to backend programming. I chose the laravel framework. Already learned the basics. During the study, the question arose: is it necessary to use the form to transfer data to the server ?. For example: the deletion route looks like this to me

`<a href="{{route('admin.complaints.delete', $complaint->id)}}">Delete</a>`.

If I leave it, will it be a mistake? Maybe advise an article or something. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **no, it's not necessary**, but you should (if you're bound to HTML only).

The [HTTP standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) has different **methods** for different purposes. Using an [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) will always make a HTTP `GET` request to the link/server, which is not ideal, `GET` request should never change the remote (server) state, that's a job other methods (`POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `PATCH`), you should try to use the method that better describe what you're trying to do: in your case I suppose you're trying to delete a complaint, so a `DELETE` or `POST` is what you're looking for.

The only way to use make a non `GET` request in plain HTML* is to use `<form>`. Also if you're planning to use a method different from `POST` you should take a look at Laravel's `@method` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#method-field)

- Mind that if you can and want to use JavaScript to perform your request you totally can, dropping the requirement to have use `form` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)).

Comment: I would say "you should if you are exclusively using plain HTML". If you are using any kind of JS framework (Vue JS, React, Angular) you can perform an Axios request without the need of using a form, such as pressing a button that hits a DELETE endpoint in the API

Comment: @Luciano yeah, you're right! I've updated my answer!  Also, I want to add that it's not necessary to use a JavaScript framework or a library to make HTTP requests, indeed you should use them only if strictly necessary.